# How can I scrape from tiprank through Google Sheet Apps Script?

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets

I am using the following Google Sheet Apps Script to **scrape** tiprank for target price.

```
function TRTP(url) {
const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
const res = html.match(/<div class="flexcb_ bgwhite h12    w12  px0  displayflex positionrelative py3">.+?(<text .+?<\/text>)/);
if (!res) throw new Error("Value cannot be retrieved.")
return res;
}
```

I am using the following URL: https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/msft/forecast

This is trying to pull data from the following snapshot from URL above.

Targetprice from Tiprank:
[image: Targetprice from Tiprank]

This should give me a long OuterHTML in which values are also present .. I use Google Sheet formula to extract target price from that.

This work on other websites like WSJ but is not working on Tiprank.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution, not so elegant

```
function TRTP(url) {
const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
var res = html;
res = res.match(/(?<=flexccc    mt3 displayflex colorpale shrink0 lineHeight2 fontSize2 ml2 ipad_fontSize3.*>).*/g)[0].substring(0,50);
res = res.match(/.*(?=<)/g)[0];
if (!res) throw new Error("Value cannot be retrieved.")
return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=importxml("https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/msft/forecast","//div[@class='flexccc    mt3 displayflex colorpale shrink0 lineHeight2 fontSize2 ml2 ipad_fontSize3']")
```

Comment: Hi. i appreciate the effort but there is a limitation in using importxml.. it can call hardly 5 to 10 symbols at a time.. appscript can handle higher number of symbols at a time..

Can you help me with a script solution...?

Comment: ok i will work on it, be patient (unless someone else resolves the request before me)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Lowest Price Target:

```
=importxml(CONCATENATE("https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/", A1,"/forecast"), "//*[@class='colorpurple-dark  ml3 mobile_fontSize7 laptop_ml0']")
```

Average Price Target:

```
=importxml(CONCATENATE("https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/", A4,"/forecast"), "//*[@class='colorgray-1  ml3 mobile_fontSize7 laptop_ml0']")
```

Highest Price Target:

```
=importxml(CONCATENATE("https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/", A4,"/forecast"), "//*[@class='colorpale  ml3 mobile_fontSize7 laptop_ml0']")
```

Comment: Please don't post the same answer to multiple questions. If two questions can be answered with the _exact_ same answer, it should be considered whether or not they are duplicates—in which case the weaker of the questions should be flagged as such. Otherwise, your answer should be customized to the specifics of the question to ensure it's addressing the particular needs of the author.